# X509 Private Key Convert to pkcs1 possible?

Tags: cryptography, type-conversion, public-key-encryption, x509, sha

Is it possible to convert a public/private key I created in PHP (x509 format  I believe but not 100% sure) to a pkcs1 version (python) ? I have two apps one PHP and one in Python, and I would like them both to use the same key pairs as they will eventually communicate with each other. It doesn't seem to be possible as far as I can tell but could anyone advise if i'm going around in circles with this, or if indeed you can make a key pair work across both programming languages by converting one of them.

My Ultimate aim is:

**Python stores** - Public key

**PHP stores** - Private Key

Then both apps perform I/O with each other.

Example of Key made in PHP below (X509)

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- 
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqh+pyERnrrSIlJFNcX5D
FI7vJVHlgN0qAVYBsRB7HHGmBXjkFhtbz0RmTE13effnNB5UJS3BzqLFAGib9JkF 
Df7HgnpdVf3pIE5g+2kL/abQ9r+U0qX7hqmwnEWyA60Htz7MpSq4p4q7CPSCeGez 
m7946u8+6jVgIX19YrrM7f4Ai6LBBEFtMG0ytnhVaKWl3kwGuHmCSRUhhZsaE4TZ 
1wce/UcAQSkmzEnflfqdc7IiM55ZPYkW8u9cIFgOhYv3du2Il9GH7E3PBt6aASH/ 
ct7MRP4gCAvoSEhn/t1/Hr/aHlSgH/OIHHK0GFrVUgZokxaYv+EWkfxC9/log5uG 
pQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----


-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- 
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCqH6nIRGeutIiU 
kU1xfkMUju8lUeWA3SoBVgGxEHsccaYFeOQWG1vPRGZMTXd59+c0HlQlLcHOosUA 
aJv0mQUN/seCel1V/ekgTmD7aQv9ptD2v5TSpfuGqbCcRbIDrQe3PsylKrinirsI 
9IJ4Z7Obv3jq7z7qNWAhfX1iuszt/gCLosEEQW0wbTK2eFVopaXeTAa4eYJJFSGF 
mxoThNnXBx79RwBBKSbMSd+V+p1zsiIznlk9iRby71wgWA6Fi/d27YiX0YfsTc8G 
3poBIf9y3sxE/iAIC+hISGf+3X8ev9oeVKAf84gccrQYWtVSBmiTFpi/4RaR/EL3 
+WiDm4alAgMBAAECggEAYWwEdFUH8vobhMi4ypd9npZDyOFfRi5g0acJDPbdKWrD 
ojqakzZTmxwWYPezxbr7QdNkaG4NoGGB4zwEo0vFo0AVzFh6frYK/J8l1pNPdJBE 
9ii79u1qXrFqG/Olf4lk88EYvDT8zaUaeoRa+syYBEbf3dnn84Nha4xLc3B5zodJ 
A1Ps31utrlHwLYJUHw81jT3aUmKJpV/dqnhb1D8FXd2PN6sNbsA1fDGSBAV5mFll 
u6F5btLwFKpSzCFgT/gbx4LFWR08ZLPpiMWXiUZm5wbBwB0lI8a4qZAXQmHqQokP 
Xj516VAqUdo0eh9sOAZu3h8YNtziOjs/bQoWsek4eQKBgQDfVH5dE7TPc5KjfbaK 
5yBGQDX0ZLMSlXCt35ad79YQlWpMGcvAu5988HiriCntHhOhSeNMNpu/QMmvVL/L 
XZvb9SRSvZzs3kEIP7mxqQi045frq5WxYB4N/nnJmSye4l8oogueTh45y2WrJxsy 
E6Oaiejx0AK5efIUEai0Wrhm5wKBgQDDAqPErtR6Mv/sMtUt76Iun+CfokEN316i 
6s1sDQRTpxCgfDFd7pK77p92LnqGoXpWQoHeRb94d7pCG8UkkvyzfHKyquq4wT2y 
UsDFJ4g+a/x63J43O/NHhW7X5ZShuSRr9+13JWD+P8aqQwIfJd23iST8o5KdDjwF 
c7jkiSYQkwKBgQCbbMhMqqxJPBuvoIvr+5Jgkct6/KILqukyeMrvu7x06ieCMum0 
hl8mqoywhCD5ntb2ht+jaNXXspUqaobYV5ti5yaSVtfhmYQU45Suaf9fNI3EPDP/ 
r+76ukGz5eBB6zVip/QCBkfO3RkylhK9NSHFKXlu4N8kihPJl8ibTA/NvQKBgG+t 
JFIveNjeOfdvCOw8jlk7D6z7g1vJbm3IH4ngTnkFdJ0jYjYTuQ5M0h8g8OQGt4OM 
pMjAkq0Pi6fuNVEDqBm1jA3LmY3ihE2J3IFLaVeuCbHmg+jHuUNdI6QaAqs21qfK 
HMCdtFUF+uRoaV+jFLzVmkvf9MdibncE1X5zGExnAoGAJp7Xe67ZvFrQH7AigXt7 
hxhsvd3/EExTWJx1aGc+aplI1dl8HR6tjBcJSR+uf2siI9B3OuLHaZZha2p/bcE6 
dt2vYbE0/oOunDiU6G3BJFE/gKIVwl4l8sknISLWO/uWg5puig3uK0wbqQawC6G5 
Ude0KAn2vkkHVAgj0oBSqNU=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing to convert, those keys are in a format that is already acceptable to many/most crypto APIs regardless of language or platform (though not all). The public key is a format that is most often called SubjectPublicKeyInfo format or spki for short. Java also supports to that format with a class called X509EncodedKeySpec, which is perhaps where the x509 label comes from. The private key is in PKCS8 PrivateKeyInfo format. You need to pick a crypto API/library and then the question can answered definitively.

Comment: @President James K. Polk ok thanks for the info in my example above my python side only supports PKSC01, and when I tried to use those keys with PHP it failed invalid key. Trying a new library is a good call though think that's the best route for now.

Comment: You should specify which PHP and Python libraries are involved. You may be overlooking import or conversion options.

Comment: @Topaco I am using OpenSSL for PHP and RSA for python. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, [RSA-Python](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/reference.html#classes) only supports the PKCS#1 format. The only exception is the import (but not the export) of the public key in X.509/SPKI format (and the import of raw keys). PKCS#8, which is more common for private keys, is not supported at all (neither for export nor import). If this is not sufficient for your scenario, you must either use another RSA library (PyCryptodome, pyca/Cryptography,...) or an additional library for (programmatic or manual) key conversion.

Comment: @Topaco thanks so much for the information. I have been learning phpseclib3 this afternoon with the hope that would do the job, but I will investigate those libraries mentioned instead.